# How to save Highcharts image on server auomatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, highcharts

I am using highcharts and Ruby on Rails to creating chart. I want to save graph as server automatically. Following code download image automatically on download folder with name as chart.png

```
events: {
  load: function () {
    var ch = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
      ch.exportChart();
    });
  }
}
```

I want to save grph as /asset/image folder with name today_Report.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can force user to save anything in folder you want to. That's about path, now about name for file, check [this](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.exportChart), example:

`chart.exportChart({ "filename": "today_Report" });`

Comment: how to save image as under /app/assets/image/ folder

Comment: As I said: `I don't think you can force user to save anything in folder you want to`. If you want to save this on your own server, then setup exporting-server on your server.